# Python, return multiple arrays in new lines

Tags: python

I have 3 arrays, a1, a2, a3

I would like to return all three of them at once.

I have

`return a1, a2, a3`
but it returns them all on the same line, I was wondering how I would return them each on a new line

Comment: What do you mean by "on the same line" or "on a new line"?

Comment: If you want to *see* the arrays each in it's own line, use `pprint` module: `import pprint; pprint.pprint(your_func())`. If it's about assignment then John's anwer is valid.

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean like this?

```
>>> def f():
...   a1 = [1, 2, 3]
...   a2 = [4, 5, 6]
...   a3 = [7, 8, 9]
...   return a1, a2, a3
... 
>>> f()
([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

You can unpack the return value like this

```
>>> b1, b2, b3 = f()
>>> b1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b2
[4, 5, 6]
>>> b3
[7, 8, 9]
```

Or print it on 3 lines like this

```
>>> print "\n".join(str(x) for x in f())
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking to be able to do

```
return a1
return a2
return a3
```

instead of

```
return a1, a2, a3
```

???

If so, I am sorry, but you cannot do that.  When you use the `return a1, a2, a3` you are actually returning one thing, a tuple of 3 lists.  Execution of a return statement will return out of the current scope/context to the caller.  If this is not what you are trying to do, please explain a little more clearly what you are after.

Comment: If he wraps the returned tuple with parens he will be able to write each element in it's line. The question is vague and I'm guessing, maybe this is what he's after?

Answer (score 1):

You can only return once from a method.  However, the data can still be accessed on separate lines.

```
def dosomething():
    ...
    return a1, a2, a3

myTuple = dosomething()
first = myTuple[0]
second = myTuple[1]
third = myTuple [2]
```

Answer (score 0):

if a1, a2 ,a3 are same length, you may try this

```
a1 = [1, 2, 3]
a2 = [4, 5, 6]
a3 = [7, 8, 9]
[ (a1[x],a2[x],a3[x]) for x in range(len(a1)) ]

>>> [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're treating an array like a string - arrays don't span "lines" per say.

Maybe this is what you're looking for; if I understood correctly.

```
 return str(a1)+'\n'+str(a2)+'\n'+str(a3)
```